# How can I use mount a NetApp NFS drive on Windows so I can create symlinks on it?

Tags: nfs, server-message-block, cifs, netapp

I tried two ways of mounting a NetApp NFS drive on a Windows server:

- Mounting using SMB/CIFS from NetApp
- Mounting as a NFS drive using Windows NFS Sevices

With none of them, Windows did not let me create junction points (Windows flavour of symlinks).

Note, I do want to keep this volume as NFS, because the same volume is mounted by other Unix systems that do need to be able to create and use these symlinks.

When mounted on Unix, this works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

[Junction points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) are only supported on NTFS file systems.  Does a [NTFS symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) work?